# ASP MVC, datepicker

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a project and this needs a date picker, so i used the default one in MVC. this works great for creating new entries in the database but when I edit it will tell me that it’s a required field but it already has a value from the creation and when I use inspect element it shows me the value.
Does anyone has an idea how I can fix this problem?

Model

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayName("Geboortedatum")]
public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

View

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BirthDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BirthDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BirthDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you rendering the HTML5 datepicker or using the jQueryUI datepicker plugin?

Comment: It’s the default HTML5 date picker, but It’s jQuery validation.

Comment: If you're using jQuery you could try removing the validation helper and validate when the form is submitted instead

Comment: Then you need to add the `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]` attribute to the property. Note the ISO format

Answer (score 0):

this did the trick, thanks for the help:)

[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]